# UITableViewCell curve line anomaly- left side. What's causing this? Image included

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, uitableview

I have this odd semicircle being drawn at the top left of each cell in this Table View.  I can't seem to be able to get rid of it. I'm not doing any custom drawing in my cells, although the cells are all subclasses of UITableViewCell.

The curved artifact appears only in the first cell in each section, and is still persistent regardless of the table view background.

[image]

This is all the custom code in the cell, the rest is in IB

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
  // NSLog(@"DataEntryCell layoutSubviews");
  UILabel *topLabel = [self parameterLabel];
  UILabel *bottomLabel = [self dataLabel];

  topLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0];
  topLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
  topLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
  topLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
  topLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);

  bottomLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
  bottomLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
  bottomLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
  bottomLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
  bottomLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

  self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
  self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
  self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
}
```

Any idea what could causing this?

Thanks

Comment: You need to share some code or more info about what have you done so far

Comment: Does your table have "grouped" style? If so - do you still have the same issue if you set it to "plain"? In grouped style table view the content view of cells is shrunk (or covered) from the sides. This might be the issue. I also think that if you had a table of three rows, only top and bottom ones would have this anomaly.

Comment: Yes, it uses the Grouped style. It's only the top cell that has this. But what is it and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: This is probably a drawing glitch. Do you get it with standard striped background?

Comment: Just checked, and yes I do still have it with the default background.

Comment: Lets try to eliminate some possibilities. Can you reproduce the issue with another tableViewController ? (NO SUBCLASSING)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything in that `layoutSubviews` that really belongs there.  All of those properties on the labels should be set when the labels are created.  Ditto for the properties on self.  The `selectionStyle` in particular seems suspicious since it mentions gray and you have a stray gray line.  By the time `layoutSubviews` is called, it's too late to set `autoresizesSubviews`; autoresizing happens before you receive `layoutSubviews`.

Try putting that stuff closer to the cell's initialization - in `awakeFromNib` if you're loading the cell (and its subviews) from a nib, or with the code that creates and adds the subviews.

Comment: This fixed the issue, thanks very much! This code was written more than a year ago and I'm now updating it. Can't believe I missed this.